# Finder item in some point

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript, finder

I am clicking with the right mouse button in some Finder's window. I am getting the location of the click (its CGPoint). How can I tell what item is in that point ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected item using below apple script

```
 tell application "Finder"
        selection
    end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do it manually if Parag Bafna's suggestion doesn't work for you. Basically a Finder item has a position property. However the coordinates you get back are in the window coordinates. I'm assuming that your CGPoint is in global coordinates so you'll have to convert the window coordinates to global coordinates. You can do that easily enough because the window has it's own coordinates so you can figure out the global coordinates of a Finder item.

So it's doable with a little work using the Finder items' position property.

```
tell application "Finder"
    tell window 1
        set theItems to items
        set oneItem to item 1 of theItems
        return position of oneItem
    end tell
end tell
```